# Ruby on Rails - Adding user in test case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I am really new to the unit testing and i am trying to wrap my head around it. So the situation I have an article form where user can enter `title` and `description` and on clicking `Create Article` article should get created but only a logged in user can perform this operation so I need to test this.

Since I am new to this so this is what I am thinking,

1. I will create a user first
2. Save it to session as thats how the system checks if the user is logged in (but then i am also thinking its not a browser so this logic might not work), then how do i submit a form as a logged in user?

here is my try

```
require 'rails_helper'

    RSpec.feature 'adding article' do
      scenario 'allow user to add an article' do
        @user = User.create(:email => "saadia1@clickteck.com", :password => 'password', :username => 'saadia1')
        session[:user_id] = @user.id

        visit new_article_path

        # @article = Article.user.to eql(@user = User.find_by(id: 6))
        fill_in "Title", with: "My Title"
        fill_in "Description", with: "My description"


        click_on("Create Article")

        expect(page).to have_content("My Title")
        expect(page).to have_content("My description")

      end
    end
```

When i run the command `rspec spec/features/add_article_spec.rb`

I see

> Failures:
>
> 1) adding article allow user to add an article
>        Failure/Error: session[:user_id] = @user.id
>
> ```
>  NameError:
>    undefined local variable or method `session' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AddingArticle:0x007f89285e32e8>
>  # ./spec/features/add_article_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```
>
> Finished in 0.0197 seconds (files took 1.35 seconds to load) 1
>   example, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/features/add_article_spec.rb:4 # adding article allow
>   user to add an article

So my question is how do i add an article as a logged in user? I will really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

are you using devise for authentication if yes devise provides some helpers for test also include this line in your rail_helper.rb

`config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller`
this will help you to use `sign_in` helper method of devise, and you wil not need to use session as you are doing currently, Please refer to [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)#user-content-controller-specs) for more information

Comment: thanks, yes I am using devise. I will try and get back

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up creating a test case, since this is my one of the first test cases ever I am not sure how this can be improved so feel free to review it

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature 'adding article' do    
  scenario 'allow user to add an article' do 
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    visit login_path
    fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
    click_button 'Log in'
    expect(page).to have_content('You have successfully logged in')


    visit new_article_path

    fill_in "Title", with: "My Title"
    fill_in "Description", with: "My description"


    click_on("Create Article")

    expect(page).to have_content("My Title")
    expect(page).to have_content("My description")

  end
end
```

This is my factory

```
# spec/factories/users
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:username) { |n| "user#{n}" }
    password 'password'
    sequence :email do |n|n
    "user_#{n}@example.com"
    end
  end
end
```

> Finished in 0.4176 seconds (files took 2.54 seconds to load) 1
>   example, 0 failures

I do still want to know if it is possible at all to login the user in another scenario or all this has to be a part of one scenario.